# Powershell downloading all possible files for a given day

Tags: powershell, csv, download, wildcard

I'm using Powershell for the first time to download the previous day's files from a webpage for a client.  The web page is from a data logger than is on a vendor skid.  The data logger always saves the files in the format `yyMMdd##.CSV`, where `##` is the sequential number file for that given day (starting at 00).  When viewing the webpage I have only seen the maximum number of CSV files for a given day as 1 (so, 8/31/17's file would be 17083100.CSV).  I have got the Powershell code written to give me yesterday's file assuming that 00 is the only file for that day, but I was hoping there was a way I could either use a wildcard or for loop to download any additional files that may exist for the previous day. See the code below for what I currently have:

```
 $a = "http://10.109.120.101/logs/Log1/"
 $b = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyMMdd") + "00.CSV"
 $c = "C:\"
 $url = "$a$b"
 $WebClient = New-Object net.webclient
 $path = "$c$b"
 $WebClient.DownloadFile($url, $path)
```

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this:

```
$Date=(get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyMMdd")
$URLFormat ='http://10.109.120.101/logs/Log1/{0}{1:D2}.CSV'

$WebClient = New-Object net.webclient

#build destination path
$PathDest="C:\Temp\$Date"
New-Item -Path $PathDest -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 

1..99 | %{

$Path="$PathDest\{0:D2}.CSV" -f $_
$URL=$URLFormat -f $Date, $_

try
{
    Write-Host ("Try to download '{0}' file to '{1}'" -f $URL, $Path)
    $WebClient.DownloadFile($Path, $URL)
}
catch
{

}

}

$WebClient.Dispose()
```